# Método split() no convierte mi cadena en array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lo que sucede es que quiero convertir una **cadena** a  un **array**, el problema, es que esa cadena la obtengo de un `<td>`, es decir, obtengo como texto `.text()` todo lo que tenga dentro ese `<td>`, y al aplicar `.split()`, no me convierte esa cadena en array, dejo un ejemplo de cómo lo que hago:

```js
//Obtengo el texto del <td>
let cadena = $('.jsTd').text();
//Aplico split para obtener el array
let resultado = cadena.split(' ');

//Me retorna array vacío (Aquí me falla)
console.log(resultado);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td class="jsTd">
  icono 320301223
</td>
```

Comment: y si imprimes cadena, si te arroja el string de tu td?

Comment: No @ProsperoAguilar, acabo de darme cuenta que no lo hace :( , peeroo.. no entiendo el porqué no lo está obteniendo con .text() si en teoría debería devolverme algo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El tag `td` es ilegal si se encuentra fuera de un `table`.  Simplemente agrega `<table>` asi:

```js
//Obtengo el texto del <td>
let cadena = $('.jsTd').text();
//Aplico split para obtener el array
let resultado = cadena.split(' ');

//Me retorna array vacío (Aquí me falla)
console.log(resultado);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<td class="jsTd">
  icono 320301223
</td>
</table>
```

Comment: era eso. Gracias por el dato, no sabía que eso tenía que ver. :D